# MySQL EXPLAIN: "Using index" vs. "Using index condition"

Tags: mysql, optimization

The [MySQL 5.4 documentation, on Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/using-explain.html), says this about these Extra remarks:

> - Using index
>
> The column information is retrieved
>   from the table using only information
>   in the index tree without having to do
>   an additional seek to read the actual
>   row. This strategy can be used when
>   the query uses only columns that are
>   part of a single index.
>
> [...]
>
> - Using index condition
>
> Tables are read by accessing index
>   tuples and testing them first to
>   determine whether to read full table
>   rows. In this way, index information
>   is used to defer (“push down”) reading
>   full table rows unless it is
>   necessary.

Am I missing something, or do these two mean the same thing (i.e. "didn't read the row, index was enough")?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

An example explains it best:

```
SELECT Year, Make --- possibly more fields and/or from extra tables
FROM myUsedCarInventory
WHERE Make = 'Toyota' AND Year > '2006'

Assuming the Available indexes are:
  CarId
  VIN
  Make
  Make and Year
```

This query would EXPLAIN with 'Using Index' because it doesn't need, *at all*, to "hit" the myUsedCarInventory table itself since the "Make and Year" index "cover" its need *with regards to the elements of the WHERE clause that pertain to that table*.

Now, imagine, we keep the query the same, but for the addition of a condition on the color

```
...
WHERE Make = 'Toyota' AND Year > '2006' AND Color = 'Red'
```

This query would likely EXPLAIN with 'Using Index Condition'  (the 'likely', here is for the case that Toyota + year would not be estimated to be selective enough, and the optimizer may decide to just scan the table).  This would mean that MySQL would *FIRST* use the index to resolve the Make + Year, and it would have to lookup the corresponding row in the table as well, ***only for*** the rows that satisfy the Make + Year conditions.  That's what is sometimes referred as "[**push down optimization**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html)".

Comment: Am I correct to assume that I'd also see "Using where" in your second example?

Comment: @Piskvor  Sorry I'm not in a position to test this, at the moment, Both queries would show as "Using where", I think.

Comment: @mjv, Your link... Page not found.

Comment: @Pacerier , I edited with an updated link.  I seems that archived documentation for mySQL is only available as PDFs or ePubs for versions other than the current and current minus 1.  The link is now current for version 5.6;  in case upgrades to mySQL and its documentation, the same can be located with the following path in the `Reference Manual`:  (8?) Optimization  (8.2?)  Optimizing SQL statements (8.2.1 ?) Optimizing SELECT statements  (8.2.1.6 ?) Index Condition Pushdown Optimization

Comment: it's not clear enough, you can not explain the different bewteen use and not use index condition.

Answer (score 11):

The difference is that "Using index" doesn't need a lookup from the index to the table, while "Using index condition" sometimes has to.  I'll try to illustrate this with an example. Say you have this table:

```
id, name, location
```

With an index on

```
name, id
```

Then this query doesn't need the table for anything, it can retrieve all it's information "Using index":

```
select id, name from table where name = 'Piskvor'
```

But this query needs a table lookup for all rows where name equals 'Piskvor', because it can't retrieve location from the index:

```
select id from table where name = 'Piskvor' and location = 'North Pole'
```

The query can still use the index to limit the results to the small sets of row with a particular name, but it has to look at those rows in the table to check if the location matches too.

Comment: "it can retrieve all it's information Using index" - it could use just the second column in a composite index? I thought that for `select id, name from table where name = 'Piskvor'` the index `(id, name)` won't be used, as opposed to index `(name,id)`. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Piskvor: You're right.  You can still do an index scan on (id,name) but an index on (name) would allow an index seek.  I'll edit the answer.