# How do I avoid "USING INDEX CONDITION" on MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query on which I believe I already have all the indexes and so I would expect the query to be processed instantly. However, the query takes several seconds to finish. Using `EXPLAIN` shows the query uses `INDEX CONDITION`:

```
+----+-------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type     | possible_keys                        | key       | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | il    | fulltext | PRIMARY,FK32F0579FBAF38C6F,name_ftx  | name_ftx  | 0       | NULL              |    1 | Using where; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | eq_ref   | PRIMARY,FK5C6729AF5D52323,...        | PRIMARY   | 8       | goout.il.thing_id |    1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | ref      | state,event_id,parent_id             | parent_id | 9       | const             |    5 | Using index condition; Using where; Distinct |
+----+-------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Please notice the third row which uses this `INDEX CONDITION`. Is there a way to find what causes it?

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id
FROM event i
JOIN event_locale il ON i.id = il.thing_id
LEFT JOIN event_schedule s ON i.id = s.event_id
WHERE (i.parent_id IS NULL)
      AND (s.state = 2 OR s.state = 3) 
      AND s.parent_id IS NULL
      AND (i.state = 2 OR i.state = 3)
      AND (MATCH(il.name) AGAINST ("jan"))
LIMIT 10;
```

I am positive I have indexes on all used columns and fulltext index on the match-against column.

Comment: After reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687548/mysql-explain-using-index-vs-using-index-condition), I'm wondering if you also have a combined index on the used `event_schedule` columns?

Comment: Kenney: the combined index really helped! Please answer this question and I will accept it.