# "Using index" with composite index: A=, B=, C<=

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, secondary-indexes, composite-index

The execution plans below seem disappointing and suboptimal, even though the queries are straightforward.

I'm using MySQL 5.7. Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a7478/16) (although it only offers 5.6).

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(63) CHARSET ASCII COLLATE ASCII_BIN NOT NULL,
  `is_sequenced` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sequence_number` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Name-SequenceNumber` (`name`,`sequence_number`),
  KEY `Name-IsSequenced` (`name`,`is_sequenced`,`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB
;

INSERT INTO `event`
(id, `name`, is_sequenced, sequence_number)
VALUES
(NULL, 'OrderCreated', 0, NULL),
(NULL, 'OrderCreated', 0, NULL),
(NULL, 'OrderCreated', 0, NULL),
(NULL, 'OrderCreated', 0, NULL),
(NULL, 'OrderCreated', 0, NULL),
(NULL, 'OrderCreated', 0, NULL),
(NULL, 'OrderCreated', 0, NULL),
(NULL, 'OrderCreated', 0, NULL),
(NULL, 'OrderCreated', 0, NULL)
;
```

We will be using the `Name-IsSequenced` secondary index. Let's try the following `EXPLAIN`. (The queries are in the Fiddle. Open "View execution plan" to see their `EXPLAIN` result.)

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * -- This part needs the PK
FROM `event` e
WHERE e.name = 'OrderCreated'
AND e.is_sequenced = 0
AND e.id <= 3
;
```

So far, so good. `Using index condition` makes sense: the entire condition can be resolved on the expected index `Name-IsSequenced`, and then the PK is needed to get the remaining data for `SELECT *`.

We should be able to improve that to `Using index` if we only select something that is part of our secondary index, right? (Note that the PK is always part of any secondary index, but we can even ensure this by including `id` at the end of our secondary index. The result is the same, as it should be.)

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT id
FROM `event` e
WHERE e.name = 'OrderCreated'
AND e.is_sequenced = 0
AND e.id <= 3
;
```

Now, the result is `Using where; Using index`. Wait, that's... worse?! We made it do less work, and the plan indicates that it is working harder.

`Using index` should be achievable. Find the range where `name=OrderCreated`, then inside it find the subrange where `is_sequenced=0`, then inside that find the subrange where `id<=3`.

Curiously, I have other experiments (with some more data) where I can get `Using index` by changing `id<=3` to `id=3` (combined with `FORCE INDEX` to prevent it from prefering to the PK). I see no reason for the difference. (If we try this with the Fiddle, it stays the same - perhaps because of the small data set.)

Can anybody explain why the execution plan does not indicate the expected efficient use of the secondary index? Is there are a way to straighten it out?

Comment: Does the `SELECT id ...` query run slower than the other one?

Comment: @SalmanA Good question. My `SQLyog` IDE crashed when I had the (more complex) queries on the larger data sets open. I'll need to set up a new test on more data to answer that.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687548/mysql-explain-using-index-vs-using-index-condition) seems to suggest that `Using where; Using index` is **better** than `Using index condition`.

Comment: @SalmanA No, I believe that post says `Using index` (without the `Using where; ` before it) is better. That's true, but that's not what we're seeing here. It's what I'd _expected_ to see, though!

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE e.name = 'OrderCreated'
  AND e.is_sequenced = 0
  AND e.id <= 3
```

The rule is simple:  Do the `=` columns first, in any order.  Then you get one crack at a 'range'.

```
INDEX(name, is_sequenced, -- in either order
      id)                 -- last
```

Do not listen to the old-wives-tale about ordering them based on cardinality.

With `SELECT id`, that index contains all the columns needed, so it is "covering", as indicated by `EXPLAIN's` "Using index".

With `SELECT *` the index is missing `sequence_number`.  So, it has two ways to be executed:

Plan A:  Use the index; for each row relevant row in the index's BTree, reach over into the Data's BTree (via `id`) to find the missing column.

Plan B:  Shun the index and simply scan the data, which is ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.  But lo and behold, `id < 3` is actually a pretty good use of the PK.  The `EXPLAIN` will probably say `PRIMARY` and `Range`.

The Optimizer will make a semi-intelligent choice between the Plans and *usually* pick the better one.

Plan C:  Plan A can be improved upon.  Add `sequence_number` (on the *end*) to make `INDEX(name, is_sequenced, id, sequence_number)`.  Now you get "covering" ("Using index") and the fastest possible index.

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

About 5.6 / 5.7 / 8.0, the Optimizer was revamped a lot.  It moved to a "cost-based model", where it uses index statistics, etc, to compute estimates of how costly each possible execution plan would be.  The change was rolled out with a lot of fanfare, but the net effect on query plans was minimal.  One area where no model does well is if the `WHERE` clause has range criteria on two different tables in a `JOIN`.  `ORDER BY` and/or `LIMIT` throw extra monkey-wrenches into the fray.

`ANALYZE TABLE` used to be important for 'fixing' the statistics; 5.6 made a fundamental improvement in that.  Still, the "statistics" are not perfect.

`id=3` -- Well, you are asking for all the columns, and using the PK has all the columns, so why even consider some secondary index.  (The PK is "clustered" with the data.)  Even if there is an index that is just as good, the data is more likely to be cached in RAM.  (The cost model does not [yet] take into account caching or SSD vs HDD.)

As a Rule of Thumb (empirically determined), a secondary index will be shunned if more than 20% of it is needed.  The bouncing back and forth between the secondary BTree and the Data BTree is assumed to be more costly than simply scanning the data.  In your *tiny* table, 30% of the index is needed.  QED.  (Actually this is another gray area in which the Optimizer sometimes "gets it wrong".)

Comment: Thanks Rick. You make a fair point about `id=3` skipping the secondary index. However, the beef of your answer seems to be explaining the `SELECT *` scenario, which already made sense (`Using index condition`). My question really asks about the `SELECT id` scenario, where the secondary index is covering, and the fact that the execution plan, counter-intuitively, seems _worse_ than for the `SELECT *` query. Perhaps I've missed it in your answer, but could you shed some light on the resulting `Using where; Using index`?

Comment: @Timo - "Using index" == "covering", a positive influence on performance.  "Using where" is a mystery to me; it feels like something slightly negative.  "Using index condition" is positive; "Using temporary" and "filesort" are negatives.  Your test case is (1) too small to be trusted, and (2) all the values are the same -- this may throw off the statistics gathering.

Comment: Fair. I do believe I also tested locally at the time, with much more data, but that does not help us much now.